# fastest way to share data between a C++ and Python program?

Tags: python, c++, c++11

I'm trying to build a algorithmic trading program. The program has execution flow like this:

```
Server sends data via websocket -> Python program receives it and sends it to C++ program -> C++ program processes the data and sends some data to Python code -> Python code sends packets to Server
```

The reason I'm not building the whole thing in C++ is because Broker's API only supports Python and I cannot perform the operations I wish to perform fast enough if I switch to Python.

The frequency of data is going to be at least ~50kb (binary and Json) per second. So far I've found the following alternatives:

1. Embed Python in C++ code. 
   This seems great, but I'm not sure if would be able to import whole library and use classes/methods (broker's client) in C++.
2. Communicate through sending packets (latency is the issue here)
3. Put the data received in SQL database and have C++ query it every X ms. (again, latency)

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: What exactly are your latency requirements?

Comment: Have you considered Cython and/or Numba? You might be able to interface reasonably well with with C using Cython (and you could expose more or less directly the relevant bits of memory), or you could implement whatever algorithm in plain Python and you could let it through a LLVM interpreter (if your constructs are simple enough).

Comment: @norok2 I'll look into Cython/Numba, LLVM thank you.

Comment: @ErikCederstrand since it's a real time application I must process received data ASAP.

Comment: @Yuckfou 50 kb/s is not an impressive throughput, and it is actually slower than typical I/O transfer on modern hardware. In real-time applications, it is far more convenient to think in terms of raster time (e.g. the minimum time required to get enough data to compute the next bit, etc.), and I would check that you first test your timings. Perhaps a Python implementation is fast enough, given that I/O-bound computation can be typically done within Python. (As a side note, "ASAP" is not a real requirement, real-time means you gets control over time, not raw fast FASTER :-) ).

Comment: @Yuckfou "ASAP" is not a requirement, and nothing is actually real-time. There's *always* a delay. You have to know your requirements, in terms of micro/milliseconds, because solutions will range from "do whatever works" to "buy the building next door to Broker and install a dedicated fiber cable".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using CPython (the most common implementation of python) then you can create a dynamic library that can be used as a python module. There
[Boost.Python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html)

Which can be used as:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

```python
> import hello_ext   
> print(hello_ext.greet())
hello, world
```

---

To build with python 3.7 and boost 1.68.0 you can use following CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project("boost_python_sample" LANGUAGES CXX)

set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/local/boost_1_68_0")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS python37)
set(Python3_ROOT_DIR "C:/python37")
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)

add_library("boost_python_sample" SHARED "main.cpp")
target_link_libraries("boost_python_sample" Boost::python37 Python3::Python)
target_compile_definitions("boost_python_sample" PUBLIC "BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB")
```

Comment: I like this answer going concrete. Perhaps, it could get even more concrete by adding some comments on the requirements and the compilation steps.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement your C++ code as shared library (so or dll).
Your interface should be `extern "C"`.
Then you can call your native functions directly in python and pass your data via pointers within the same process and memory.
To call the native functions you can use [Python CTypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Answer (score 2):

One way to exchange data between python and C++ is to use a message queue library. One possible library which is designed to be fast is [ØMQ (zeroMQ)](http://zeromq.org/). Is this the fastest way? It depends on your use case. It might be worth evaluating. Especially considering the easy to implement part, good documentation and community support.